# Regular expression to match non empty xml tags using Notepad++

Tags: regex, tags, notepad++

The xml file contain multiple  tags, some of which has a value and some are blank, like

```
<main>
  <text></text> <text>   </text> <text></text> <text>test str</text>
  <text></text>
</main>
```

as you can see that there is only one non empty text tag, In npp how do I find such non empty tags in xml using regular expressions. I don't want the expression to match the tags with white-spaces.

So after performing find it should match **`<text>test str</text>`**

I have tried `<text>(\S+)</text>` but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex, which looks for a `<text>` tag followed by some number of spaces then a non-space character, using a negative lookahead to assert that we are not at the closing tag:

```
<text>\s*(?!</text>)\S.*?</text>
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b0EV3e/1)